# How can I get the current location URL of Mozilla browser using C#?

Tags: c#, firefox, browser, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Firefox URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430614/get-firefox-url)

I am facing a problem while developing my Windows application for getting current URL of running Mozilla Firefox  browser. Is it possible to get active URL of Mozilla Firefox browser?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the accessibility APIs to read the location bar.

Mozilla 0.x/1.x, Netscape 6.x/7.x and SeaMonkey 1.x/2.x make this easier for you by posting the current URL to a hidden edit control in the window.

Answer (score 0):

moz=DDE&&||ui peeking

IE=com

Moz Beware:Tabbed browsing makes it impossible to tell which urls are currently open, you can only poll/monitor a windows url